# SSRS 2008 two column report only shows data on the left column

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2008, ssrs-2008, multiple-columns

I am creating a new report that needs to show data in two columns.  I did the following:

1. Report Properties: added the second column
2. Insert a List control from the toolbox
3. Insert a rectangle inside the List control
4. Insert a textbox inside the Rectangle

When I click on Preview tab, the report only shows data in the left column and then continues to the 2nd page in the same way instead of using the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

List controls are not really needed. If you place the data in two tables or textboxes at the same height, they will display next to each other. If you have to, place both in a rectangle or set the KeepTogether property.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it only works in "Image" and "PDF" export formats. From the [relevant documentation on columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255278.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Columns are only applied when you render and print reports **in PDF or Image formats**.

The "Preview" window doesn't use the PDF or Image renderer.

Personally, I'm a little surprised that it hasn't been implemented in the MS Word renderer, but I've tested this and indeed it doesn't work there either.

A little earlier in the same documentation, it hints at the inner workings of the "columns" feature:

> ...For example, suppose you have two columns on a **physical page**. The content of your report fills the first column and then the second column. If the report does not fit entirely within the first two columns, the report fills the first column and then the second column on the next page. ...

My guess is that in the Preview window, you'll never get to the end of a ***physical*** page, so the content never flows to the second column. If you export to -say- PDF, you'll probably get the behavior you're expecting.

Note that the columns do actually have to *fit* in the report, make sure your report's and report body's width and margins are set correctly.